Which sample autocovariance sequence estimate should I use for spectral analysis?
Is there any reason to choose a biased autocovariance sequence estimate over an unbiased estimate for power spectral density analysis? Why would we want to introduce bias into our estimate of the power spectral density?

TL;DR
While bias does decrease resolution in spectral estimators, there are two primary reasons the biased autocovariance sequence should be used. The first is that the unbiased ACS is indefinite, which can lead to negative spectral estimates, where as the biased ACS is positive definite (see Why does the unbiased sample autocorrelation sequence not peak at lag 0?). The other reason is that there is equivalence between the periodgoram and the correlogram for the biased ACS estimate, whereas the unbiased ACS estimate does not achieve this equivalence.
Proof
One reason why the biased autocovariance sequence estimate is important for spectral estimation is that it gives equality between the periodogram and correlogram, under the mild assumption that
\begin{equation} 
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-N}^{N}\left\lvert k\right\rvert c[k] = 0
\end{equation}
First, we have two definitions of the power spectral density
\begin{align}
\phi(\omega) &= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}c[k]e^{-j\omega k} \\
\phi(\omega) &= \lim_{N\to\infty}E\left\{\frac{1}{N}\left\lvert\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}y[k]e^{-j\omega k}\right\rvert^{2}\right\}
\end{align}
We assume $y$ is a sequence of zero-mean random variables. In the practical case, the sample mean is subtracted from the signal $y$.
Proving this equality, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty}E\left\{\frac{1}{N}\left\lvert\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}y[k]e^{-j\omega k}\right\rvert^{2}\right\} = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}E\left\{y[k]y^{*}[l]\right\}e^{-j\omega\left(k-l\right)}
\end{align}
Plugging in $\tau = k-l$, we get
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}E\left\{y[k]y^{*}[l]\right\}e^{-j\omega\left(k-l\right)} &= \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\tau=-N+1}^{N-1}\sum_{k-l=\tau}E\left\{y^{*}[l]y[l+\tau]\right\}e^{-j\omega\tau} \\ &= \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\tau=-N+1}^{N-1}\left(N-\left\lvert\tau\right\rvert\right)c[\tau]e^{-j\omega\tau} \\ &= \sum_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty}c[\tau]e^{-j\omega\tau}-\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\tau=-N+1}^{N-1}\left\lvert\tau\right\rvert c[\tau]e^{-j\omega\tau}
\end{align}
Under the mild assumption previously mentioned, these two are equivalent, i.e. under the assumption the autocorrelation function decays sufficiently rapidly.
We then wish to show that the biased estimate meets this condition. In fact, we will show that the biased estimate meets an even stricter condition
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=-N+1}^{N-1}\hat{c}[k] = 0; \; \forall \; N
\end{equation}
To prove this is a stricter condition is straightforward. The original condition can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-N+1}^{N-1}\left\lvert k\right\rvert c[k] &= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}kc[k] + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}kc[-k] \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}kc[k] + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}kc^{*}[k] \\ &= 2\mathbb{R}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}kc[k]
\end{align}
For this sequence to approach 0 as $N\to\infty$, the unweighted sum
\begin{equation}
2\mathbb{R}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}c[k]
\end{equation}
must approach 0 sufficiently rapidly such that it beats out the weighting by $k$. Thus, if
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=-N+1}^{N-1}c[k]=0 \; \forall N
\end{equation}
this ACS meets the original constraint.
To prove the biased ACS satisfies the stricter condition, the following is recognized
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-N+1}^{N-1}\hat{c}[k] &= \hat{c}[0] + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\hat{c}[k]+\hat{c}[-k] \\ &= \hat{c}[0] + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\hat{c}[k]+\hat{c}^{*}[k] \\ &= \hat{c}[0] + 2\text{Re}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\hat{c}[k]
\end{align}
For the autocovariance sequence, the mean is 0, but this proof applies for non-zero means without loss of generality. This gives
\begin{equation}
0 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x[k] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x[k]
\end{equation}
What is interesting is that the term $\hat{c}[0]$ represents all of the "auto" terms, and the term $2\text{Re}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\hat{c}[k]$ represents all of the "cross" terms! Therefore, this can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\hat{c}[0] + 2\text{Re}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\hat{c}[k] &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=0}^{N-1}x[t]x^{*}[t] + 2\text{Re}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=k+1}^{N-1}x^{*}[t]x[t+k] \\ &\propto \begin{bmatrix}x[1] & \cdots & x[N]\end{bmatrix}^{2} \\ &= \left(\sum_{t=1}^{N}x[t]\right)^{2} = 0
\end{align}
Also notice that, for the unbiased estimate, the scaling $\frac{1}{N}$ would need to be changed to $\frac{1}{N-k}$. Since this scaling is not constant, we would not get the same equality for the unbiased estimate. Therefore, we have the biased estimate of the ACS meets the condition for the periodogram to be equivalent to the correlogram, giving another bonus to why the biased estimate of the ACS should be used in spectral analysis.
