A proof of Wiener–Khinchin theorem without change of variables
I wonder if the following proof of Wiener–Khinchin theorem (for stochastic signals) is wrong:
We'll be first proving the Wiener–Khinchin theorem for deterministic power signals, and then we will just take the ensemble average of both sides of the equation to get the stochastic version.
The Wiener–Khinchin theorem for deterministic power signals states that the power spectral density (PSD) of a deterministic power signal $x(t)$ (denoted $S_{xx}(f)$) is the Fourier transform of its autocorrelation function (denoted $R_{xx}(\tau)$), i.e.,
\begin{equation}
    S_{xx}(f) = \mathcal{F}\{R_{xx}(\tau)\}.\tag{1}
    \label{eq:deter}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    S_{xx}(f) := \frac{1}{T} \left|\widehat{x_T}(f)\right|^2.
    \label{2}
    \tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    R_{xx}(\tau) := \frac{1}{T} \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{x_T(t-\tau)} x_T(t)  \mathrm{d}t.
    \label{3}
    \tag{3}
\end{equation}
($\widehat{x_T}$ means the fourier transform of the truncated signal $x(t)$ by a window of length $T$, we also implicitly let $T \to \infty$).
The proof is very simple: ( $\flat$ means taking time reversal and complex conjugate)
\begin{align*}
    S_{xx}(f) & = \frac{1}{T} \left|\widehat{x_T}(f)\right|^2  \\
    & = \frac{1}{T} \overline{\widehat{x_T}(f)} \widehat{x_T}(f)  \\
    & = \frac{1}{T} \mathcal{F} \left\{{x^{\flat}_T} * x_T\right\}  \\
    & = \frac{1}{T} \mathcal{F} \left\{\int_\mathbb{R} {x^\flat_T}(\tau-t) x_T(t) \mathrm{d}t\right\}  \\
    & = \frac{1}{T} \mathcal{F} \left\{\int_\mathbb{R} \overline{x_T(t-\tau)} x_T(t) \mathrm{d}t\right\}  \\
    & = \mathcal{F} \left\{\frac{1}{T} \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{x_T(t-\tau)} x_T(t) \mathrm{d}t\right\}  \\
    & = \mathcal{F}\{R_{xx}(\tau)\}.
\end{align*}
Now let's move on to stochastic signals. We can view a deterministic signal as a sample path (or realization) of a stochastic process. Therefore, we can simply take the ensemble average of equation \eqref{eq:deter}, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}[S_{xx}(f)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{F}\{R_{xx}(\tau)\}]
    \label{4}
    \tag{4}
\end{equation}
The LHS of equation \eqref{4} is exactly the definition of the PSD of a stochastic signal:
\begin{equation}
    S_{XX}(f) := \mathbb{E}[S_{xx}(f)] = \int_\Omega S_{xx}(f, \omega) \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}
    \label{5}
    \tag{5}
\end{equation}
If we define the autocorrelation function of a wide sense stationary (WSS) stochastic process $X: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$:
\begin{equation}
    R_{XX}(\tau) := \langle X(t-\tau)|X(t) \rangle = \int_\Omega \overline{X(t-\tau, \omega)} X(t, \omega) \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{E}[\overline{X(t-\tau, \omega)}X(t, \omega)]
    \label{eq:stoc}
    \tag{6}
\end{equation}
We could proof that the RHS of equation \eqref{4} is exactly the fourier transform of $R_{XX}(\tau)$:
\begin{align*}
    \text{RHS} = \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{F}\{R_{xx}(\tau)\}] = \mathcal{F}\{\mathbb{E}[R_{xx}(\tau)]\},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[R_{xx}(\tau)] & = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{T} \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{x_T(t-\tau)} x_T(t) \mathrm{d}t\right]  \\
    & = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{T} \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{X_T(t-\tau, \omega)} X_T(t, \omega) \mathrm{d}t\right] \\
    & = \frac{1}{T} \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{E}[\overline{X_T(t-\tau, \omega)} X_T(t, \omega)] \mathrm{d}t  \\
    & = \frac{1}{T} \int_\mathbb{R} R_{X_TX_T}(t-\tau, t) \mathrm{d}t  \\
    & = \frac{1}{T} \int_T R_{XX}(\tau) \mathrm{d}t \\
    & = R_{XX}(\tau).
\end{align*}
which completes the proof.
It seems that this proof is simple and organized. But I never seen this elsewhere. Does it have any problems?

There's one primary issue that I would note that would seems to cause problems (not saying you couldn't come back with a corrected proof, but that currently stands in the way).
The power spectral density of a deterministic signal, or of a single realization of a random process is not
\begin{equation}
S_{xx}(f) = \frac{1}{T}\left\lvert \widehat{x_{T}}(f)\right\rvert^{2}.
\end{equation}
That is a finite sample approximation known as the periodogram, which is asymptotically unbiased and inconsistent. The definition in this case would be
\begin{equation}
S_{xx}(f) = \lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\left\lvert \widehat{x_{T}}(f)\right\rvert^{2}.
\end{equation}
Now if we take the expected value, we achieve the definition of the power spectral density of a random process.
The problem with this technicality is that, assuming there are an infinite number of possible realizations of a random process, you have a double integral over two infinite domains. By Fubini's theorem, switching the order of integration may not be valid, since both the expectation and the Fourier transform would be integrals over an infinite domain. My guess is that it would not be valid, though, as realizations of a random process modeled as wide-sense stationary don't have finite energy, and therefore don't possess DTFT's. My intuition is that this property of random signals would violate the condition for which the double integral can be computed via an iterated integral, making the switch invalid. However, I haven't worked out that proof, so could be proven wrong. Of course, in practical scenarios where you have a finite number of realizations that are considered a "good enough" approximation of the ensemble, and a finite number of samples, this problem evaporates.

Thanks for your answer! You said that a realization $x(t)$ of a WSS process may not Fourier-transformable, that's true indeed, but we are doing Fourier transform to its truncated version, i.e. $x_T(t)$, which is of finite duration and must have Fourier transform. I think letting $T \to \infty$ is acceptable for engineers though. But recently I realized that isn't my proof just the idea of Ergodic theory? Compare Equation (3) (time average) and (6) (ensemble average).

@MarkRen the problem is that, in the finite sample case, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are only equal under certain assumptions on the autocorrelation function (see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/95335/which-sample-autocovariance-sequence-estimate-should-i-use-for-spectral-analysis/95336#95336). Using $\lim_{T\to\infty}$ alleviates this issue. As for ergodicity, yes, it would appear that is assumed going from $(3)$ to $(6)$.
